# How to setup send HTML email with mail gem?

Tags: html, ruby, email, mime-types

I am sending email using the Mail gem. Here's my code:

```
require 'mail'
require 'net/smtp'

Mail.defaults do

delivery_method :smtp, { :address              => "smtp.arrakis.es",
                       :port                 => 587,
                       :domain               => 'webmail.arrakis.com',
                       :user_name            => 'myname@domain.com',
                       :password             => 'pass',
                       :authentication       => 'plain',
                       :enable_starttls_auto => true  }

end

Mail::ContentTypeField.new("text/html") #this doesnt work

msgstr= File.read('text2.txt')

list.each do |entity|
    begin
        Mail.deliver do
            from    'myname@domain.com'
            to      "#{entity}"
            subject 'a good subject'
            body   msgstr
        end
    rescue => e
    end

end
end
```

I don't know how to set up the content type, so that I can format my email as html for example. Though I actually just wish to be able to define bold text like my email client does: **bold text**. Does anybody know which content-type I need to specify in order to achieve this, and how to implement it with mail?

Just a note, the code above works fine for sending plain text email.

Comment: wow, i wanted to say **bold text** but it came out as *bold text* so here its two asterisks not one...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mikel/mail#writing-and-sending-a-multipartalternative-html-and-text-email)

> **Writing and sending a multipart/alternative (html and text) email**
>
> Mail makes some basic assumptions and makes doing the common thing as
>   simple as possible.... (asking a lot from a mail library)
>
> ```
> mail = Mail.deliver do
>   to      'nicolas@test.lindsaar.net.au'
>   from    'Mikel Lindsaar <mikel@test.lindsaar.net.au>'
>   subject 'First multipart email sent with Mail'
>
>   text_part do
>     body 'This is plain text'
>   end
>
>   html_part do
>     content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
>     body '<h1>This is HTML</h1>'
>   end
> end
> ```

Comment: thanks a lot! i was reading through the documentation and wasn't able to find this... i guess i didn't think i would simply find it in the examples.

Comment: `text_part do` then `content_type("text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed")` this allows to write bold text in between 2 asterisks

Comment: grrrr no it doesn't, my thunderbird shows it in bold but shows the asterisks as well, weird, and in other mail clients does nothing at all... do you know how i should specify the content type to allow basic formatting like (asterisk)bold text(asterisk) without having to step into html?

Comment: You can't. There is no standard for this, flowed format is a Mozilla extension that is not widely supported across all clients. The only way is to use HTML.

Answer (score 4):

@Simone Carletti's answer is essentially correct, but I was struggling with this and didn't want a plain text portion to my email and a separate HTML portion. If you just want the entire email to be HTML, something like this will work:

```
mail = Mail.deliver do
  to      'nicolas@test.lindsaar.net.au'
  from    'Mikel Lindsaar <mikel@test.lindsaar.net.au>'
  subject 'First email sent with Mail'
  content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
  body '<h1>This is HTML</h1>'
end
```

I may have missed it, I didn't see anything in the Mail gem documentation describing how to do that, which I would think would be more common than making a multipart message. The documentation only seems to cover plain text messages and multipart messages.