# Gem "mail" is ignoring its body

Tags: ruby, email, rubygems, rack

I'm sending an email using "mail" gem in non-rails app:

```
  mail = Mail.new

  # ..........
  # it returns html
  mail.body = ERB.new(File.read(File.expand_path("templates/email/main.html"))).result(binding)

  # mail.body does contain html now
  # ......
  mail.attachments["something.pdf"] = File.binread(.....)
```

And debugging:

```
    [1] pry(TicketMailer)> mail.body
    => #<Mail::Body:0x00007f6f48823890
     @ascii_only=true,
     @boundary=nil,
     @charset="US-ASCII",
     @encoding="7bit",
     @epilogue=nil,
     @part_sort_order=["text/plain", "text/enriched", "text/html", "multipart/alternative"],
     @parts=
      [#<Mail::Part:70057967292360, Multipart: false, Headers: <Content-Type: application/pdf; filename="tickets.pdf">, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary>, <Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tickets.pdf">, <Content-ID: <fdsfs343243243432@fdsafdsfds.mail>>>],
     @preamble=nil,
     @raw_source=
      "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />\n  [...........]  </body>\n</html>">
    [2] pry(TicketMailer)>
```

Yet, an email comes with the empty body. Why and how to fix this?

Comment: You have to set the content-type as well. You can check this approach - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340006/how-to-setup-send-html-emails-with-mail-gem

Comment: @arjun that doesn't work. I also have an attachment and I see the content of an attachment as the body. not the body itself